# printf is not giving output when using system

Tags: c

I have following code(part of code):

```
snprintf(
    command,
    sizeof(command),
    "%s -o %s -n \"%s\" -st %s -et %s -a \"%s\"",
    _pcOPMTRExePath,
    _pcTempFile,
    l_acHostName,
    _pcStartTime,
    _pcEndTime,
    l_acMessage
);
printf("%s",command);
l_iRetValue = system(command);
/* Return an error if failed to copy*/
if(l_iRetValue!=0)
{
    printf("18");
    return INTERNAL_ERROR;
}
```

The issue is system command is working fine.
But my printf is not giving the command value.
Is this the issue of memory overflow or like that?

Comment: You've been on the site for eight months, and asked eight questions. By now you should know how to format code in a question (and if not: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Please don't make other people do it for you.

Answer (score 6):

It might just be that stdout isn't getting flushed - often stdout is linebuffered when connected to a console. Try either

```
printf("%s\n",command);
```

or

```
printf("%s",command);
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that it's just stdout not getting flushed after the printf. Try adding `fflush(stdout)` after the printf.

Answer (score 2):

Probably buffering. Try putting a `\n` at the end of the format string.